# Is there simple way to find out which column don't have enough width?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a table with a lot of column with varchar(65535), but it is not a good suggestion as per https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/redshift-high-disk-usage, I've create another table with better datatype but when I do

```
insert into newtable select * from oldtable
```

There some column I don't assign enough length for new column. However, there are a lot difference columns and it is hard to check one by one, is there some way I can know which column have problem? For now I only get error like this

```
Query 201601 caught Exception:
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Value too long for character type
  code:      8001
  context:   Value too long for type character varying(20)
  query:     201601
  location:  string.cpp:219
  process:   query1_125_201601 [pid=21317]
  -----------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that you run octet_length() on all the "oldtable" varchars - see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_OCTET_LENGTH.html

Here's why - once you find which column is causing this issue for the current query you will likely just find the next issue.  This could be with a different column or just a later row in the same column.  You will be in a loop increasing varchar lengths over and over again.  It is best to get out in front of it.

Use octet_lenght(), not len() as this will give the needed byte size, not just the character length.

This will take a minute to set up but once it runs for all varchar columns you will have all the data to redefine "newtable" once.  You may want to add a little pad to these columns for future, longer data but other than that you will be good to go.